# Insert image into SQL Server 2008 Express database without front end application

Tags: image, sql-server-2008

I am working with test data in Visual Studio's server explorer. How would I put images into the database just as test images? I have no front end component built to take care of image uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work for SQL server 2008r2...but first u have to create a filestream database.

//create databse

```
CREATE DATABASE Archive 
ON
PRIMARY ( NAME = Arch1,FILENAME = 'c:\data\archdat1.mdf'),
FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup1 CONTAINS FILESTREAM( NAME = Arch3,FILENAME = 'c:\data\filestream1')
LOG ON  ( NAME = Archlog1,FILENAME = 'c:\data\archlog1.ldf')
GO
```

//table creation

```
Use Archive
GO
CREATE TABLE [FileStreamDataStorage]
(
[ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FileStreamData] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL,
[FileStreamDataGUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
[DateTime] DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
ON [PRIMARY]
FILESTREAM_ON FileStreamGroup1
GO
```

//inserting value

```
Use Archive
GO
INSERT INTO [FileStreamDataStorage] (FileStreamData)
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\image1.jpg' ,SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can upload an image into a db (and retrieve it) using *byte[]* as data type, assuming that in your db corresponding column is a *BLOB*.
So if you load your image with `byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes(your_file)` then you can use a query like this `INSERT INTO table SET image_col = @par`, where *par* is a parameter whose value is *img*.

Comment: Is it possible you can point me to a good link that explains and illustrates this? I am still just a novice at sql and you lost me at BLOB.

Comment: Also, I am researching this a bit and found out that in my actual database the datatype that BLOB corresponds to is varbinary(MAX).

Comment: @HelloJonnyOh: BLOB stays for _Bynary LOng Object_, you can imagine it like a byte array. So you can insert or retrieve data to/from a BLOB using normal queries in which data sent/received to/from blobs is byte[]. Quite easy.

Comment: @HelloJonnyOh: which database are you using? SQL Server? MySql?

Comment: I am using SQL Server Express.

Comment: @HelloJonnyOh: what's the problem with my answer? I think it's clear enough to solve your problem. If not, ask me your doubts and I'll try to solve them...